# Is there a way load map in specific language?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using [Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial), and the map language is set according to user's browser locale.

Is there a way to change this setting and force map to load in US English?

There is [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Region), but it changes the region language, i.e. street names etc., I also want to control the map buttons and the interface language.

Comment: [**Language Localization**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Localizing the Map</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            html, body, #map-canvas {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script>
            function initialize() {
              var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
              };
              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                  mapOptions);
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And you can load map in any specific language by passing the value of **language** code parameter with in this

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
```

Some example language codes are given here:

pass **en** for load map into english similarly **ja** for Japanese and 
**fr** for French

I hope this is what you are asking for.

for more info click [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-language)

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.9&sensor=true&language=sa"></script>
```

i am using languague of saudi arabia